# Diffusion to growing adsorbing sphere

Tags: diffusion

I'm working on a model where particles with concentration $\phi$ diffuse to an adsorbing sphere. For the non-growing case, I assume a steady-state solution  and Fick's second law $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}= D \nabla^2\phi$ reduces to Laplace's equation. With boundary conditions $\lim_{r \to \infty}\phi(r)=\phi_{\infty}$ and the inward flux $\mathbf{J}=-\Gamma\phi|_{r=a}\mathbf{\hat{r}}$ where $a$ is the radius of the sphere. $\Gamma$ quantifies the rate at which particles go through the sphere's surface. For finite $\Gamma$ it is easy to show that $\phi(r)=\phi_{\infty}\left(1-\frac{\Gamma a^2}{(D+\Gamma a)r}\right)$. Now I want to extend the model to consider an exponentially growing sphere, but I don't know how to get started. I suppose an steady state solution can no longer be assumed. Any help on how to get started would be much appreciated.

Comment: It seems that for the case of a non-growing sphere $\Gamma$ is a characteristic of the medium. First, you should probably figure out how $\Gamma$ needs to change to account for the extra adsorption due to the sphere growing.